# How to use the WP Rocket Lazy Load Placeholder php filter to change placeholder image

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add a placeholder image for the rocket loader lazy load plugin.

The documentation states I can use the following filter to change the placeholder image :

```
apply_filters( 'rocket_lazyload_placeholder', $placeholder );
```

> Description Filters the lazyload placeholder on src attribute
>
> Parameters $placeholder: (string) The placeholder string. Defaults to
>   data:image of size 1px X 1px for images and about:blank for iframes.

There is a sample code given :

```
add_filter( 'rocket_lazyload_placeholder', function() {
    return 'http://example.com/loading.gif';
}
```

However this throws a php error because the 'add_filter(' is not closed (as far as I can deduce).

> PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?>',
>   expecting ',' or ')' in your code on line 3

I believe the source code that we are trying to replace in the plugin is :

```
$placeholder = apply_filters( 'rocket_lazyload_placeholder', 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAEACAkQBADs=' );

$html = sprintf( '<img%1$s src="%4$s" data-lazy-src=%2$s%3$s>', $matches[1], $matches[2], $matches[3], $placeholder );

$html_noscript = sprintf( '<noscript><img%1$s src=%2$s%3$s></noscript>', $matches[1], $matches[2], $matches[3] );
```

My php isn't the greatest so whatever I've tried has not worked. Would very much appreciate if someone could help me correct/figure this out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else needs this I've found the solution.

```
add_filter( 'rocket_lazyload_placeholder', function( $placeholder ) {
    $placeholder = 'your-spinner-url-here';
    return $placeholder;
} );
```

Add to active theme/child functions.php